# Cannot pass arguments to JavaScript file using config.yaml in OctoPrint events API

Tags: javascript, yaml, event-hooking, octoprint

I am trying to pass parameters to a JavaScript file which will be executed using NodeJS.

The JavaScript file contains following function:

```
function handleEvent() {

    var options = { method: 'POST',
        url: 'http://'+LOCAL_PC_ADDRESS+'/events/job/started',
        qs:
            { filename: 'example/file.gcode',
                testArguments: process.argv },
        headers:
            {
                'cache-control': 'no-cache' } };

    request(options, function (error, response, body) {
        if (error) throw new Error(error);

        console.log(body);
    });
}
```

In which a field `testArguments` is used to check the arguments passed to this file.

If I run:

```
node myscript.js "foo" "bar"
```

Into returned POST I get what I expect:

```
{ filename: 'example/file.gcode',
  testArguments:
   [ '/usr/bin/node',
     '/home/pi/prototype-rasp/myfile.js',
     'foo',
     'bar'
] }
```

And until now it is all okay.

The problems come when I use [OctoPrint API event hooks](http://docs.octoprint.org/en/master/events/index.html), I configure **events** into **config.yaml** as shown in the docs. Part of this **config.yaml** is reported here:

```
events:
  enabled: True
  subscriptions:
    - event: Connected
      command: /usr/bin/node /home/pi/prototype-rasp/myscript.js "foo" "bar"
      type: system
      enabled: true
```

I tried also using `command: /usr/bin/node /home/pi/prototype-rasp/myscript.js -- "bar" "foo"`. I fire the OctoPrint event that correctly found the yaml event hook, launches the script but there are no arguments in `process.argv`, missing *foo* and *bar*.

Any idea how to solve it?